# Implementing a generic method from interface?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a self created generic interface "BoundedQueue" with an array as the underlying structure. When I compile my partly complete class "BoundedQueueArray", I get the errors:

```
3 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Awet\CSC 143-Jinguji_NSCC\Week 6\csc143\data_structures\BoundedQueueArray.java  [line: 11]
Error: csc143.data_structures.BoundedQueueArray is not abstract and does not override abstract method insert(java.lang.Object) in csc143.data_structures.BoundedQueue
File: C:\Users\Awet\CSC 143-Jinguji_NSCC\Week 6\csc143\data_structures\BoundedQueueArray.java  [line: 20]
Error: generic array creation
File: C:\Users\Awet\CSC 143-Jinguji_NSCC\Week 6\csc143\data_structures\BoundedQueueArray.java  [line: 32]
Error: name clash: insert(T) in csc143.data_structures.BoundedQueueArray and insert(T) in csc143.data_structures.BoundedQueue have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

Here is the class:

```
package csc143.data_structures;

public class BoundedQueueArray<T> implements BoundedQueue {

  // elements stored in array
  private T[] elements;
  // the number of elements currently in the queue
  private int numElems;

  public BoundedQueueArray(int capacity) {
    // instantiate and bind to reference 
    elements = new T[capacity];

    numElems = 0;
  }

  /**
   * This method inserts the specified element, unless the
   * queue is full.
   * 
   * @param o The element to be inserted.
   * @throws FullQueueException If the queue is full.
   */
  public void insert(T o) throws FullQueueException {
    if(numElems < elements.length) {
     elements[numElems] = o;
     numElems++;
    } else {  // queue is full, cannot add element
      throw new FullQueueException("Queue is full.");
    }

  }

  /**
   * This method returns the element at the front of the
   * queue, unless the queue is empty.
   *
   * @return The element at the front of the queue. 
   * @throws EmptyQueueException If the queue is empty.
   */
  public T front() throws EmptyQueueException {

  }

  /**
   * This method retrieves and removes the element at the front
   * of the queue, unless the queue is empty.
   * 
   * @return The element at the front of the queue.
   * @throws EmptyQueueException If the queue is empty.
   */
  public T remove() throws EmptyQueueException {
    if(length() == 0) {
      throw new EmptyQueueException("Queue is empty.");
    }

  }

  /**
   * This method reports whether or not the queue contains
   * element(s).
   * 
   * @return If one or more element exists or not.
   */
  public boolean hasMember() {
    return length() > 0;
  }

  /**
   * This method reports whether the queue has space to add
   * element(s).
   * 
   * @return If space exists or not.
   */
  public boolean hasSpace() {
    return elements.length - length() > 0;
  }

  /**
   * This method returns the capacity of the queue.
   * 
   * @return The capacity of the queue.
   */
  public int capacity() {
    return elements.length;
  }

  /**
   * This method returns the current length of the queue.
   * 
   * @return The length of the queue.
   */
  public int length() {
    return numElems;
  }

  /**
   * This method provides a string representation of the queue.
   * 
   * @return The String representation of the queue.
   */
  public String toString() {

  }

}
```

Here is the interface it implements:

```
package csc143.data_structures;

public interface BoundedQueue<T> {

  /**
   * This method inserts the specified element, unless the
   * queue is full.
   * 
   * @param o The element to be inserted.
   * @throws FullQueueException If the queue is full.
   */
  public void insert(T o) throws FullQueueException;

  /**
   * This method returns the element at the front of the
   * queue, unless the queue is empty.
   *
   * @return The element at the front of the queue. 
   * @throws EmptyQueueException If the queue is empty.
   */
  public T front() throws EmptyQueueException;

  /**
   * This method retrieves and removes the element at the front
   * of the queue, unless the queue is empty.
   * 
   * @return The element at the front of the queue.
   * @throws EmptyQueueException If the queue is empty.
   */
  public T remove() throws EmptyQueueException;

  /**
   * This method reports whether or not the queue contains
   * element(s).
   * 
   * @return If one or more element exists or not.
   */
  public boolean hasMember();

  /**
   * This method reports whether the queue has space to add
   * element(s).
   * 
   * @return If space exists or not.
   */
  public boolean hasSpace();

  /**
   * This method returns the capacity of the queue.
   * 
   * @return The capacity of the queue.
   */
  public int capacity();

  /**
   * This method returns the current length of the queue.
   * 
   * @return The length of the queue.
   */
  public int length();

  /**
   * This method provides a string representation of the queue.
   * 
   * @return The String representation of the queue.
   */
  public String toString();

}
```

Comment: if you really want to use array to store your objects, have a look how it is solved in java api, ie, in ArrayList, all elements are store in array `Object[]` and when get is calles, they are casted to type `T`

Comment: @user902383: Could you elaborate on that? It would help to see an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You cannot create an array of a generic type parameter.
2. You cannot declare a method with a type parameter as its argument which will match an existing method's signature after erasure. This is happening because you are implementing a raw type.

So, you should declare your class like this -

```
public class BoundedQueueArray<T> implements BoundedQueue<T>
```

and remove the following array creation code from the constructor -

```
elements = new T[capacity];
```

It will be better if you can use a `List` ([interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) in place of the array (see [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 25), and stay away from raw types as much as possible (see [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 23).

Example -

```
private List<T> elements;    // convert array to list
```

and -

```
elements = new ArrayList<T>();    // create instance like this
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How would I get around instantiating the array in the constructor?

Comment: Also, is it possible to accomplish this a different way and still having an array as the underlying structure?

Comment: @user2581779: `ArrayList` uses a resizable array internally to store its elements, but you probably can't explicitly use an array to store your elements. Since you'd want to parameterize your queue implementation to be used with different types, then you need to parameterize the elements, and you cannot use arrays with a type parameter. If you would really like to use array, then do not use generic at all, typecast your elements to and from `Object`, but this is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Actually, it appears I need to implement this without utilizing the java.util package. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @user2581779: Yes, it is. Use a Linked List data structure to store your elements. Do not use an array.

Comment: Well, I am trying to do both implementations: one with an array as the underlying structure and the other with a linked list as the underlying structure. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @user2581779: Try something by yourself first. If you get stuck, come back here again with the specific problems that you are facing. I would suggest you again to stay away from the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
private T[] elements;
```

this line is the problem. generic arrays are not allowed as far as i know.

use a `List` instead

Answer (score 0):

as i said in my comment, go to have a look to implementation of ArrayList to have some ideas

as every object in java implements `Object`, in ArrayList you can see elements are store in `Object[]`

`private transient Object[] elementData;`

as you know type of array, you can initialize it without problems

your insert will be exactly same, as whatever T is, it will always inherit Object

getting object out from ArrayList is very simple as well, all what you need to do is cast it to your generic type

```
     public E get(int index) {  
       RangeCheck(index); //irrevelant for your example
       return (E) elementData[index];
     }
```

if i missed anything, go and have a look [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html)

Comment: Thank you, I ended up figuring out how to cast it to the generic type.